# Node.js Sequelize ORM error with sourceKey on many-to-many relationship

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, model, sequelize.js

I have an error with [Sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize) model.

I have two models: `Hostel` and `Faculty`. And I need many-to-many relationship between them.

I added to `Hostel` the next:

```
Hostel.belongsToMany(Faculty, {
  through: 'university.hostels_to_faculties',
  sourceKey: 'hostel_id',
  targetKey: 'faculty_id',
  onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});
```

Full code source is here: https://github.com/ASUDR/backend/blob/dev/src/db/models/university/Hostel.ts#L41

And when I run this code, I get an error:

> /opt/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js:129
> this.sourceKeyField = this.source.rawAttributes[this.sourceKey].field || this.sourceKey;

(here is arrow that points out to field at this.source.rawAttributes[this.sourceKey].field)

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'field')
> at new BelongsToMany (/opt/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js:129:69)
> at Function.belongsToMany (/opt/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/mixin.js:64:25)
> at file:///opt/app/dist/db/models/university/Hostel.js:24:8
> at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:183:25)
> at async Loader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:178:24)
> at async Object.loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:68:5)
> at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:63:12)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by creating the model for junction table:

```
import Sequelize, { Optional } from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../../sequelize';

const { DataTypes, Model } = Sequelize;

export interface FacultyHostelsAttributes {
  id: number;
  hostelId: number;
  facultyId: number;
}

export interface FacultyHostelsAttributesInput extends Optional<FacultyHostelsAttributes, 'id'> {}
export interface FacultyHostelsAttributesOutput extends Required<FacultyHostelsAttributes> {}

export class FacultyHostels
  extends Model<FacultyHostelsAttributes, FacultyHostelsAttributesInput>
  implements FacultyHostelsAttributes {
    public id: number;
    public hostelId: number;
    public facultyId: number;
}

FacultyHostels.init({
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },

  hostelId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    field: 'hostel_id',
    allowNull: false
  },

  facultyId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    field: 'faculty_id',
    allowNull: false
  }
}, {
  sequelize,
  schema: 'objects',
  modelName: 'faculty_hostels',
  timestamps: false
});
```

And changing `belongsToMany` arguments:

```
Hostel.belongsToMany(Faculty, {
  through: FacultyHostels,
  onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});

Faculty.belongsToMany(Hostel, {
  through: FacultyHostels,
  onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});
```

more: https://github.com/ASUDR/backend/blob/main/src/db/models/university/Hostel.ts